# C++ explicit integral user-defined conversion

Tags: c++, type-conversion, c++14, user-defined-types

I have a flags class witch is just a wrapper around an integer and I want to implement explicit conversion to to arbitrary integers types based on the conversion rules for the underlying integer type.

i.e.

say I have the class along the lines of (ignoring non-relevant members)

```
class Flags {
    unsigned int v;
    explicit operator unsigned int() { return v; }
}
```

could I still convert to an integral type other than int say by

```
unsigned long long iflags = static_cast<unsigned long long>(flags);
```

rather than

```
unsigned long long iflags = static_cast<unsigned int>(flags);
```

or would I need to explicitly define a conversion operator for every integral type to be able to do this?

Note I'm using C++14

I've read http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator but can't see any thing specific to integral types which makes me think I need to explicit define all valid conversion which I want to avoid. I would also be happy with a template conversion function which will fail if conversion to the target type isn't possible, noting I know the max value of the internal integer i.e. all flag bits turned on, as a macro/constant `FLAGS_MAX`, if this is of any use.

Comment: While compilers may contain bugs and non-standard extensions, you could get a hint if you just *tried it* first.

Comment: `explicit` *conversion operators* need to be called explicitly or by some intentional casting. Doing `static_cast<unsigned long long>(flags);` will be requesting for a conversion operator `operator unsigned long long ()` which isn't what you have, hence the program is ill-formed.

Comment: From the current answers the first point first is as I had expected, but no one has mentioned weather their is an easy way say using template to define all integral conversions that are valid, give the size of my flags class. I also understand that this would work for implicit conversions however I don't want my class to be implicitly convertible to integral types as this avoids accidental conversions. However I also don't want to have to think about what the underlying type is when I do an explicit conversion so long as my target type can hold all the flag bits.

Answer (score 1):

> could I still convert to an integral type other than int say by
>
> ```
> unsigned long long iflags = static_cast<unsigned long long>(flags);
> ```

No, you can't.

The above is equivalent to:

```
unsigned long long temp(flags);
unsigned long long iflags = temp;
```

The first line is wrong since `flags` cannot be implicitly converted to `unsigned long long`.

Given the definition of `Flags`, the only legal C++ method to initialize `iflags` is to use:

```
 unsigned long long iflags = static_cast<unsigned int>(flags);
```

---

If you remove the `explicit` qualifier from the conversion operator

```
class Flags {
    unsigned int v;
    public:
       operator unsigned int() { return v; }
}
```

then you can use

```
unsigned long long iflags = static_cast<unsigned long long>(flags);
```

Comment: What does "Standard Conversion Sequence" have to do with, well, anything?

Comment: @T.C., The compiler could convert a `Flags` to an `unsigned int` and then the `unsigned int` to an `unsigned long long` if `Flags` -> `int` were a standard conversion. That was my thought.

Comment: So? It can do that too if the `operator unsigned int` weren't `explicit`, but that still isn't a standard conversion. In any event, this doesn't have much to do with the ability to form implicit conversion sequences; of course an *explicit* conversion function cannot be used to form an *implicit* conversion sequence, standard or not, exact type match or not.

Answer (score 1):

That `static_cast` attempt falls under [[expr.static.cast]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/expr.static.cast#4), which roughly says that you can do `static_cast<T>(e)` if you can do `T t(e);` for some invented variable `t` (there's some fun dance in the wording to take care of guaranteed elision and C-style cast oddities, which we can ignore for our purposes).

That initialization is controlled by [[dcl.init]/17.7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/dcl.init#17.7), which says you do overload resolution on the conversion functions of `Flags`, with a pointer to [[over.match.conv]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/over.match.conv), which has this to say about candidates:

> Those non-explicit conversion functions that are not hidden within
>   [`Flags`] and yield type [`unsigned long long`] or a type that can be
>   converted to type  [`unsigned long long`] via a standard conversion
>   sequence are candidate functions. For direct-initialization, those
>   explicit conversion functions that are not hidden within [`Flags`] and
>   yield type  [`unsigned long long`] or a type that can be converted to
>   type  [`unsigned long long`] with a qualification conversion are also
>   candidate functions.

Your `explicit operator unsigned int()` neither yields `unsigned long long` nor a type that can be converted to it via a qualification conversion (which is irrelevant here - that conversion only applies to pointer-y things); it is therefore not a candidate. Since the candidate set is empty, overload resolution fails, so the initialization is ill-formed, and so is the `static_cast`.